# css3/ExtJs word wrap on tooltip (chrome issue)

Tags: css, google-chrome, extjs, extjs4.2

http://jsfiddle.net/zk96q/3/  (the problem only appears in chrome)

I am trying to word wrap german and apparently the phrase Kunden-/Lieferantenposition
should be wrapped after the /

```
Kunden-/
Lieferantenposition
```

I tried using word-wrap: break-word; but that wrapped like:

```
Kunden-
/Lieferantenposition
```

How can i do this using either extjs or css3 (the prefered option)

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a newline character `\n` like this:

```
title="Kunden-/\nLieferantenposition"
```

Comment: this is changing the string, i wanted to do it with CSS.